# mediaStream wont stop after unmount

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So i have a Nextjs `page.tsx` that request user media device (web cam) when the page is loaded, i did handled unmount(clean up/stop mediaStream) in my code but it does not seems to be working.

Extras question: How to stop the media device when user is not active on the current page say `example/page.tsx` ?

**Implemetation**

```
"use client"

import * as React from "react"
import {
  type Input,
  type Input as InputType,
} from "@/assets/playground/data/inputs"

import { generateUUID } from "@/lib/utils"


export default function PlaygroundEditor() {
  // Inputs
  const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState<InputType[]>([])
  const [selectedInput, setSelectedInput] = React.useState<Input>()
  const [mediaStream, setMediaStream] = React.useState<MediaStream>()

  const handleDevices = React.useCallback(
    async (mediaDevices) => {
      setInputs(
        mediaDevices
          .filter((device) => device.kind === "videoinput")
          .map((device) => ({
            id: generateUUID(),
            name: device.label,
            type: "device",
            selected: device,
          }))
      )
    },
    [setInputs]
  )

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const requestDevice = async () => {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          video: true,
        })

        setMediaStream(stream)
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    }

    requestDevice().then(() => {
      navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(handleDevices)
    })

    return () => {
      if (mediaStream) {
        mediaStream.getVideoTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop())
      }
    }
  }, [handleDevices])

  // Timer
  const [timer, setTimer] = React.useState("00:00:00")

  // Models
  const [selectedModel, setSelectedModel] = React.useState<Model>(models[0])

  return <div>hi<div/>
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you're experiencing an issue where the mediaStream is not stopping after the component is unmounted. This might be due to the asynchronous nature of the getUserMedia and enumerateDevices functions.

To ensure that the mediaStream is stopped when the component is unmounted, you can modify your cleanup function in the useEffect hook. Instead of directly returning the cleanup function, you can define a variable (cleanupFunction) to hold the cleanup logic and then return it. This ensures that the cleanup logic is synchronous.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const requestDevice = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
      });

      setMediaStream(stream);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  const handleUnmount = () => {
    if (mediaStream) {
      mediaStream.getVideoTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
    }
  };

  requestDevice().then(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(handleDevices);
  });

  return handleUnmount;
}, [handleDevices, mediaStream]);
```

By defining the handleUnmount function and returning it directly, you ensure that the cleanup logic is synchronous and executed when the component is unmounted. This should address the issue of the mediaStream not stopping after unmounting.